# I am trying to setup selenium with maven but am getting this error when declaring driver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to set up a selenium project with the maven build tool.

I have defined the dependencies but am still getting this error in the script.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Did you add the _Selenium JARs_? Your snapshot doesn't covers that.

Comment: I don't see any error information in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot suggests that you don't have `org.openqa.selenium`. As this is part of Selenium Java, you will need to include this dependency in your pom file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.11.0